# How to get the display area of a picture inside a picture box?

Tags: c#, image, winforms, picturebox

I have 2 questions:

1. How to get the display area of a picture inside a picture box with a scale factor?

   - Example:

     - I have an image (1000 x 1000), my task is "get an area (600 x 600) of that image".
     - I create a form, then a panel with a picture box inside, picture box size is 400 x 400, make some code to allow user to drag image inside the box
     - I load the image into the picture box. Since the desired area is 600 x 600, but my box is 400 x 400 only, so I scale the image with the 0.67 factor.
     - User will select the desired area by dragging the image arround.
   - How can I get that area (from the original image)?
2. And if I allow user to zoom in/out in that picture box, how can I deal with it?

Comment: What did you try. Can you post your code?

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε
I don't know where to start. My current solution is use the Control.DrawToBitmap function, but I think it is not the correct way.

Comment: It is a lot of work. I will give you a hint for the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the image is scaled in `picbox`, you can not take the area directly from picbox. The trick is to `un-scale` the rectangle that the user select and tranform it to the original one.

You need two images:

```
Bitmap original600x600; //unscaled
Bitmap picBoxImage; //with 400x400 dimensions
```

when your form loads:

```
original600x600 = new Bitmap(600, 600);
//Draw the portion of your 1000x1000 to your 600x600 image
....
....

//create the image of your pictureBox
picBoxImage= new Bitmap(400, 400);

//scale the image in picBoxImage
Graphics gr;

gr = Graphics.FromImage(picBoxImage);

gr.DrawImage(original600x600, new Rectangle(0, 0, 400, 400));

gr.Dispose();
gr = null;

pictureBox1.Image = picBoxImage; //If at any time you want to change the image of
                                 //pictureBox1, you dont't draw directly on the control
                                 //but on picBoxImage and then Invalidate()
```

When the user select a rectangle, lets call it `rectangleSelect`, on `pictureBox1` you need to transform `x, y, width, height` of rectangle to the original one, the 600x600. You need some simple math:

```
//scaled                    unscaled             with precision
x      becomes -----------> x * (600 / 400)      (int)( (double)x * (600D / 400D) )
y      becomes -----------> y * (600 / 400)      (int)( (double)y * (600D / 400D) )
width  becomes -----------> width * (600 / 400)  (int)( (double)width * (600D / 400D) )
height becomes -----------> height * (600 / 400) (int)( (double)height * (600D / 400D) )
```

Hope this helps a little!

Comment: Thanks alot, 
I got your idea for the 1st question, I can make it to work now
About the 2nd quesiton, I think it's the same as the 1st question, but I need to do some more math with the 2nd scale factor.
I'm developing a photo collage application, those 2 questions is a step in the final process.

Comment: @haiduong87 It depends on what zooming you want to achieve. If you want to just zoom in-out is easy. But if you want to zoom in-out a selected portion of picbox then it needs some work